# covariance of two vectors in scilab

Tags: statistics, covariance, scilab

In order to estimate some value , I need to calculate covariance of two matrix in scilab .As a result I need a scalar not a covariance matrix.
Should I use the function corr in scilab or cov ?

Answer (score 0):

Scalar covariance makes sense for covariance of two vectors, each of them representing some observations of one variable. If this is the meaning of your data, which simply happens to be arranged in a matrix, then flatten it before applying `cov`. The function `cov` will return a symmetric 2 by 2 matrix in which the diagonal entries are variances of each vector, and the off-diagonal entry is their covariance. Pick that one:

```
c = cov(A(:), B(:))
scalar_covariance = c(1,2)
```

Comment: I tested your code in scilab but it returns a matrix not a scalar ?

Comment: Is that a symmetric 2 by 2 matrix? If so, the off-diagonal entry (1,2) is what you want. The diagonal entries are the variances of each vector.